# bash how to divide numbers in bash based on a string in yaml file

Tags: bash

I have some `yaml` files, and the following files are two samples:

`file1.yaml`:

```
-
    name: Saeed
    amount: '4500000.00'
    billingcycle: Annually
-
    name: David
    amount: '9000000.00'
    billingcycle: Monthly
-
```

`file2.yaml`:

```
-
    name: Matthew
    amount: '8400000.00'
    billingcycle: Annually
-
    name: Tom
    amount: '12000000.00'
    billingcycle: Quarterly
-
    name: Sarah
    amount: '2400000.00'
    billingcycle: Semi-Annually
-
```

I'm trying to do this with a `while` loop for all `.yaml` files I have:

```
If billingcycle==Quarterly, then divide the value of `amount` by 3.
If billingcycle==Semi-Annually, then divide the value of `amount` by 6.
If billingcycle==Annually, then divide the value of `amount` by 12.
If billingcycle==Monthly, then store the value of `amount` (don't do any divisions).
```

The expected output should be two files:

`file1.txt`:

```
375000
9000000
```

`file2.txt`:

```
700000
4000000
400000
```

This is what I tried (may not be related to the question):

```
while read -r line
do
    billing="$(grep -B2 billingcycle "$line")"
    echo "$billing..."
done < <(ls ./*.yaml)
```

This is what I got:

```
    name: Saeed
    amount: '4500000.00'
    billingcycle: Annually
--
    name: David
    amount: '9000000.00'
    billingcycle: Monthly...
    name: Matthew
    amount: '8400000.00'
    billingcycle: Annually
--
    name: Tom
    amount: '12000000.00'
    billingcycle: Quarterly
--
    name: Sarah
    amount: '2400000.00'
    billingcycle: Semi-Annually...
```

But I expected the `...` after each `billingcycle.

**Edit 1**

This is an attempt with `case`:

```
while read -r cycle
do
    # echo "this is $cycle."
    case $cycle in
        Annually)
            total="$(( "amount" / 12 ))"
            echo "$total"
        ;;
        Semi-Annually)
            total="$(( "amount" / 6 ))"
            echo "$total"
        ;;
        Quarterly)
            total="$(( "amount" / 3 ))"
            echo "$total"
        ;;
        Montly)
            total="$(( "amount" / 1 ))"
            echo "$total"
        ;;
        *)
        echo "nothing"
    esac
done < <(find . -name '*.yaml' -exec cat {} \;)
```

But I get this:

```
nothing
nothing
...
```

Comment: Create an associative array that maps the billing cycles to the divisor.

Comment: This will be easier to do with `awk`. Do you have to do it in `bash`?

Comment: @Barmar I need more hints to what you suggested. Regarding `awk`, there's no limit on using `awk`. It can be done with `bash` too.

Comment: Don't use `grep`. Read the file line by line. If it begins with `amount` assign the second field to the `amount` variable. If it begins with `billingcycle`, use a `case` statement or associative array to divide `$amount` by the appropriate value, and print the result.

Comment: you have 2 issues ... *1)* the grep returns multiple lines into the variable `billing` so when  you issue the `echo` the `...` goes on the end of the last line in `billing`; you can see this if after `billing=$(grep ...)` you add `typeset -p billing` to see what's in `billing` ... *2)* nowhere in your code are you doing any division; as currently written it seems you have 2 different/separate issues (multi-line `grep` result vs math/division) which should, ideally, be split into 2 separate questions

Comment: also ... `bash` is limited to integer-based math so you'll need something else (`bc`, `awk`, `perl`, etc) to perform the math/division, especially if you need to display float/real values

Comment: @Barmar I'm reading the docs related to `case`, but I cannot understand how to do it properly. I'm reading https://linuxize.com/post/bash-case-statement/ as example, besides some other websites.

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks. The `grep` I use to print `...` is only an example to check if I can try first steps properly (in which I failed). That's related to what I'm trying to achieve I think.

Comment: Does your files really contain a line with only one `-` at the end?

Comment: @Cyrus yes, it does.

Comment: Why isn't it obvious? `case $cycle in Annually) total=$((amount/12);; Quarterly)) total=$((amount/3));; ... esac`

Comment: You might want to use something like [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to parse the yaml. If you do try to use grep or even awk, be aware of whatever variations are legal in the yaml or accept that it will only work on a well-behaved subset of possible inputs.

Comment: @Barmar I think that's because you're more advanced in `bash` than me and it's the first time I'm learning `case` statement. I edited the question, I get no output.

Comment: If you couldn't figure it out from the examples at that link, I don't think you really gave it much of a try. They show exactly how to use it.

Comment: Please re-read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: with the latest update (includes an example of a `case` generating the wrong result) ... what's in the `bash` variable named `cycle`? after the `do` and before the `case` ... again ... add `typeset -p cycle` to see what's actually in the `cycle` variable; do you see any instances where `cycle` consists of (only) the strings `Annually` or `Semi-Annually` or `Quarterly` or `Montly` (misspelled)

Comment: @DavidConrad thanks, I tried `yq` before for other issues but I had some errors and I totally ignored using this. I think using `awk` is better for me to understand.

Comment: @Barmar yes you're right. I'm seeing what's wrong with my tries.

Comment: next issue with the latest update (failing `case` example) ... dividing `"amount"` by a number; this is stating that you want to devide the literal string `amount` by a number ... which should generate an error; I'm guessing you meant something like `"$amount"` but this raises the next issue ... at no point is the variable named `amount` ever populated so the resulting division will be something like `"" / 3` (ie, empty string divided by a number), another error

Comment: once you the `amount` variable populated you should hit an error related to an invalid value in the division; hint: what does `echo $(( 123.00 / 4 ))` generate?

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, English is not my first language but I have no issues reading English articles and texts. But I think my issue is forgetting things:( I should re-read it multiple times to become more advanced.

Comment: @markp-fuso with `typeset -p cycle`, I did edit the question. With `echo ...`, result is `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator`.

Comment: From the output you have posted, I can not see the content of the variable `cycle`.

Comment: @user1934428 the user Barmar hinted the `case` statement with `$cycle` variable in a loop. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: From the fact that `nothing` is printed, I would conclude that `cycle` does not have any of the values you are testing. For this reason, it would be of interest to see what is actually stored in `cycle`: `printf %s\n $cycle`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to process YAML content, consider using a YAML processor.

For example, using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (or [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq)), your task could be solved with the following filter:

```bash
filter='
  .[] | objects | (.amount | tonumber) / {
    Quarterly: 3, "Semi-Annually": 6, Annually: 12, Monthly: 1
  }[."billingcycle"]
'
```

```bash
yq "$filter" file1.txt  # or:  gojq --yaml-input "$filter" file1.txt
375000
9000000
```

```bash
yq "$filter" file2.txt  # or:  gojq --yaml-input "$filter" file2.txt
700000
4000000
400000
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a YAML-aware tool/parser makes this much easier.

Of the languages "usually installed by default":

- [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)comes with a yaml parser in its stdlib

(Although Python, Perl, et al. have YAML parsers available.)

```bash
ruby -r yaml -e '
ARGV.each {|filename|
  lines = YAML.load(File.open filename).compact.map {|account|
    account["amount"].to_f / { 
      Quarterly: 3, "Semi-Annually": 6, Annually: 12, Monthly: 1 
    }[account["billingcycle"].to_sym]
  } 
  IO.write filename.chomp("yaml") + "txt", lines.join("\n") + "\n"
}
' ./*.yaml
```

Result:

```bash
$ bat file[12].txt
───────┬─────────────────
       │ File: file1.txt
───────┼─────────────────
   1   │ 375000.0
   2   │ 9000000.0
───────┴─────────────────
───────┬─────────────────
       │ File: file2.txt
───────┼─────────────────
   1   │ 700000.0
   2   │ 4000000.0
   3   │ 400000.0
───────┴─────────────────
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really, Really, REALLY need (?) to do this in `bash` ...

One verbose `bash` idea:

```
while read -r fname
do
    echo "###### ${fname}"

    while read var value rest_of_line
    do
        if [[ "${var}" = "amount:" ]]
        then
            amount="${value//\'/}"
        elif [[ "${var}" = "billingcycle:" ]]
        then
            case "${value}" in
                'Annually')             div=12    ;;
                'Semi-Annually')        div=6     ;;
                'Quarterly')            div=3     ;;
                'Monthly')              div=1     ;;
                *)                      unset div ;;
            esac

            result='error'
            [[ -n "${div}" ]] && result=$(echo "scale=0; ${amount} / ${div}" | bc)
            echo "${amount} / ${div} = ${result}"
        fi
    done < "${fname}"
done < <(find . -name '*.yaml')
```

This generates:

```
###### ./file1.yaml
4500000.00 / 12 = 375000
9000000.00 / 1 = 9000000

###### ./file2.yaml
8400000.00 / 12 = 700000
12000000.00 / 3 = 4000000
2400000.00 / 6 = 400000
```

Answer (score 1):

A shell is not a tool to manipulate text. A shell is a tool to manipulate (create/destroy) files and processes and sequence calls to other tools. Awk is the mandatory POSIX tool for general text manipulation and as such it can be called from any shell when necessary to manipulate text in the absence of any other tool designed to manipulate text that has a specific structure (e.g. `yq` for `yaml`).

So, assuming you only have mandatory POSIX tools plus bash and that your input always looks like the examples your provided then using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN {
        div["Quarterly"]     =  3
        div["Semi-Annually"] =  6
        div["Annually"]      = 12
    }
    $1 == "amount:" {
        gsub(/\047/,"")
        amt = $2+0
    }
    $1 == "billingcycle:" {
        if ( $2 in div ) {
            amt /= div[$2]
        }
        print amt
    }
' "${@}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file1.yaml
375000
9000000
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file2.yaml
700000
4000000
400000
```

Comment: Thanks, but in great numbers it's showing scientific numbers, like 13000000/12 is `1.08333e+06`.

Comment: Then use `printf` instead of `print` and specify whatever output format you want. Also, now that you know that's a potential issue, edit the sample input/output in your question to include that number so we can see if it's an issue or not when we test with the sample input/output you provide.